# why dependencies exclude invalid in gradle

Tags: gradle

I am exclude dependencies using this in gradle 6.0.1:

```
    dependencies {
        api("com.sportswin.misc:soa-misc:+") {
            changing = true
            exclude group: 'redis.clients', module: "jedis"
        }
    }
```

but when I using dependencies command to check:

```
gradle :soa-misc-biz:dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath|grep -v "(*)"|grep -C 300 "redis.client"
```

the output shows contains jredis to version 2.9.1 , why the exclude jar invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want no trace of `jedis` in your dependencies, I recommend to use the `dependencyInsight` task which will tell you why a given dependency is included.

With `./gradlew dependencyInsight --configuration runtimeClasspath --dependency jedis` you will have a clear view of all the dependency edges in the graph that end up pulling `jedis` into your project.

Answer (score 1):

You only excluded it from a single dependency. It can still be pulled into by another dependency. You can try to exclude it from everywhere like:

```
// Kotlin DSL
configurations.all {
    exclude(mapOf(
        "group" to "redis.clients",
        "module" to "jedis"
    ))
}
```